# Anonymus functions in matlab

Tags: matlab, optimization, anonymous-function

I want to optimise a function with parameters in matlab. Here is how I do it with a function when I want to optimise only one parameter:

```
fminsearch(@(x) fun(x, 3, 1, 2, 3),2);
```

It works fine. However, when I want to optimise two parameters of my function:

```
fminsearch(@(x, y) fun(x, y, 1, 2, 3),[2,2]);
```

I get the following error:

> Error using test>@(x,y)fun(x,y,1,2,3) (line 7)
>
> Not enough input arguments.

I don't understand, what's wrong with my code. It is similar to what Mathworks suggests for my problem:
http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fminsearch.html

Here is the example from the website:

```
function f = myfun(x,a)
f = x(1)^2 + a*x(2)^2;
x = fminsearch(@(x) myfun(x,a),[0,1])
```

This is exactly what I do with my function *fun*, yet, it doesn't work. Why?

Comment: It's not *exactly what you do*, MathWorks uses `@(x)`, whilst you use `@(x,y)` within the `fminsearch`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fminsearch` always assumes a single-input function, yours is double-input, as [@Adriaan noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35103432/anonymus-functions-in-matlab#comment57927856_35103432). If you have multiple parameters, use *an array-valued input* to `fminsearch`, but only a single one. That's exactly what the example is doing: passing `@(x) myfun(x,a)` with parameter `a` (not seen by `fminsearch`) and an *array* `x`.

You have to call your function like

```
fminsearch(@(x) fun(x(1), x(2), 1, 2, 3),[2,2]);
```

in order to adhere to the syntax expected by `fminsearch`.

The implementation of `fminsearch` and related functions is such that they look at the starting parameters (`[2,2]`), and they conclude the number of parameters from the dimensions of that variable. Consequently arrays of the same size are always fed to your anonymous function as its single input variable.

Comment: Bonus points for mentioning me, although I don't know anything about the functions :D